# Datastax Enterprise 5.0.3 Solr High CPU and High I/O Usage On One Node While Others Idle

Tags: performance, solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

One of my solr ode in my Solr Datacenter cause High CPU and high I/O. In some way, it affects my solr queries to other solr nodes. When i stop the node cause high cpu, my queries response in normal time.

Thanks to this link https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop i was able to get that data. I also see the node indexing something but other nodes in the solr data has no load. the load is 0-2 while, the failing node has 20 load.

```
   1273 http-serveripaddress-8983-5           RUNNABLE 51.16%     1.87%
   3821 http-serveripaddress-8983-14          RUNNABLE 50.41%     0.95%
   1259 http-serveripaddress-8983-2           RUNNABLE 48.68%     2.49%
   1295 http-serveripaddress-8983-7           RUNNABLE 48.10%     1.87%
   3825 http-serveripaddress-8983-18          RUNNABLE 14.15%     0.75%
   1308 http-serveripaddress-8983-9           RUNNABLE 14.13%     4.44%
   3486 http-serveripaddress-8983-11          RUNNABLE 13.38%     1.04%
   1258 http-serveripaddress-8983-1           RUNNABLE 12.52%     2.03%
   1264 http-serveripaddress-8983-4           RUNNABLE 12.07%     1.68%
   1296 http-serveripaddress-8983-8           RUNNABLE 12.04%     3.75%
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieDoubleField" name="TrieDoubleField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieIntField" name="TrieIntField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieDateField" name="TrieDateField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieLongField" name="TrieLongField"/>
</types>
<fields>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="st" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="twd" stored="true" type="TrieDoubleField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="ctr" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="us" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="tsb" stored="true" type="TrieDoubleField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="btrg" stored="true" type="TrieIntField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="cty" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="hc" stored="true" type="TrieIntField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="isp" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="cnt" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="scid" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="cip" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="sid" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="pd" stored="true" type="TrieDateField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="uid" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="lfn" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="devg" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="str" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="tcc" stored="true" type="TrieLongField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="strg" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="dev" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="lfs" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="cid" stored="true" type="TrieIntField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="btr" stored="true" type="TrieIntField"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>(cid,pd,scid,lfn,lfs,uid,sid,cip,strg,str,st,btrg,btr,hc,us,devg,dev,cnt,ctr,cty,isp)</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your partitioning is leading to hotspots on your data.  A common example is to bucket stuff by the day or hour when loading time series data.  The net effect is that only one node at a time will be used during the bucket period.

The other thing to look at is the value of max_solr_concurrency_per_core.  The defaults can be too high - I'd normally recommend dropping it to 2 - and then gradually increasing until the server maxes out.  What are your server hardware specs like, in terms of memory, cpus and disks?

Comment: I have 64GB ram two raid1 disks, one for solr data, one for cassandra data, one ssd for commit log, 32 core with hyper thread. Indeed, my max_solr_concurrency_per_core = 2 and  i have very little user querying solr. @nom de plume

Comment: I usually try to get ssds for the solr data - but for low load what you've got should be ok.

I'd recommend looking at the data model next.  Do you have the schema and can you give us some idea of how the data is inserted?

Comment: I am also considering using ssd but Opscenter says one node has 150 GB data but when i check solr disk it says 1.5 TB used space. I put one of my schema. The others goes around the same schema. @Nom de plume

Comment: I don't think I've seen that many fields in the uniqueKey before!  What's the equivalent cql schema showing as?  Essentially I want to know what your partition key is on.